# Angular Highcharts not rendering 3d views (from highcharts package)

Tags: typescript, charts, highcharts, 3d, angular8

**Reference github issue link**: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12598

**Description**: When using 3d column, 3d cylinder or 3d pie, 2d view is getting rendered instead of 3d view though 3d options are set.

**Related Code**

```
  const options: any = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart rotation demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Test options by dragging the sliders below'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
    };
    Highcharts.chart('columnChart', options);
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor? You can use this template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-example I am not able to see your data or rest of the config which could have an impact for the chart working.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipzzrg

Comment: In the demo which you have shared the 3D module is missed, which is required to get 3D charts works. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maewa6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. Updated the working solution on Stackblitz